# How to access a variable inside a service using a controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, angular-controller

Im having two html screens, in first screen Im getting an input and saving it in a service, so that the same value is accessed by another controller and display the value in the second screen. Here Im able to store the value from the first html screen to the service but the problem is faced while accessing the value using another controller. So how to access the value in the service from another controller and what is the mistake made here.

Service:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.service('variableProperties', function() {
this.sampleVariable= function(data){
    var dataStored= 'data';
return {
    getString: function() {
        return dataStored;
    }}}});
```

Controller 1 :

```
app.controller('controller1',function($scope, variableProperties){
  $scope.submit= function(formData){
     variableProperties.sampleVariable($scope.name);
     $state.go('screen2.html');
   }
   })
```

Controller 2:

```
app.controller('controller2',function($scope, variableProperties){
        $scope.getData = variableProperties.getString();
})
```

Comment: What error are you getting on console devtool (if any)?

Comment: Its your service, the code does not make much sense at all. This is usually the result of sloppy formatting, its easy to overlook a bracket in the wrong place. Reformat your service function and you should be able to catch your error easily.

Comment: Im getting getString is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Its your service, the code does not make much sense at all.

Here is a service that returns a new instance with a clear getter and setter and storage for the data.

```
app.service('variableProperties', function() {
    var newService = {};
    newService.data = ""; // (optional) initialize the storage variable to some empty string

    // define a setter
    newService.sampleVariable = function(data){
      newService.data = data;
    }
    // define a getter
    newService.getString = function() {
      return newService.data;
    }

    // return the newly defined service
    return newService;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your service,  Change it as  follows,

```
app.service('variableProperties', function() {
  var dataStored;
  var sampleVariable = function(data) {
    dataStored = data;
  }
  var getString = function() {
    return dataStored;
  }
  return {
    sampleVariable: sampleVariable,
    getString: getString
  };
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('Controller1', function($scope, variableProperties) {
  $scope.someData = "i am from controoler 1";
  variableProperties.sampleVariable($scope.someData);
});
app.controller('Controller2', function($scope, variableProperties) {
  $scope.lists = variableProperties.getString();
});
app.service('variableProperties', function() {
  var dataStored;
  var sampleVariable = function(data) {
    dataStored = data;
  }
  var getString = function() {
    return dataStored;
  }
  return {
    sampleVariable: sampleVariable,
    getString: getString
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">     
        <div ng-controller="Controller1">
    <ul>
      controller 1
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="Controller2">
    <ul>
      <li>
        controllert 2 section {{lists}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script type=" text/javascript " src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.js "></script>
  <script type="text/javascript " src="MainViewController.js "></script>
</body>
</html>
```